# Fast fourier transform for an audio file

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, digital-communications

I need to do FFT on an audio file(to be exact it is a real number array of audio samples). But the output of FFT should be complex numbers. I have a hard time understanding how to convert this.
For example: input is int input[N], and what to do next to get the output.re[] and output.imp[]? Should I treat input as a complex array only all the imaginary components equal to 0?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is so "basic", so "fundamental", that I may be misunderstanding its true meaning. In any case, hopefully you have some software routine available to you that performs FFTs and will accept your 'int input[N]' sequence as an input. I have no idea what software 'package', or software language, you're using but if variable 'x' is your input sequence then there should be some available command (or subroutine) like

```
Spec = fft(x)
```

you can use to compute your FFT spectral results. And there should be no need for you be concerned about defining your input sequence as complex-valued. Of course the length of your input sequence (number of samples) must be an integer power of two. Your FFT results will automatically be in the form of a sequence of complex numbers, so there's no need to worry about that.